# No JSON response received from HttpUrlConnection into TextView in mobile app

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to retrieve data from Thingspeak in JSON to post to the mobile app I am developing(Getting a JSON response from Thingspeak: [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/get-a-channel-feed.html)). I have made a test app to just set a value received from Thingspeak in a `TextView` but nothing has appeared on the screen of the app. The logcat has no errors pertaining to that either but has some warnings which appears with even nothing in the app(without any JSON codes)

This is the `MainActivity.java` :

```
package com.example.teerna.testapp;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView tv;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.MyAppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
    new GetMethodDemo().execute();

}

public class GetMethodDemo extends AsyncTask<String , Void ,String> {
    String server_response;



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        //URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/357670/feeds/last");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                server_response = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Converting InputStream to String
    private String readStream(InputStream in) {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                }   catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return response.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        super.onPostExecute(response);

        if (response != null) {
            String item=null;
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject jsonResponse = json.getJSONObject("Response");

                item = jsonResponse.getString("created_at");

            } catch (JSONException j) {
                j.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.e("Response", "" + server_response);
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(item));
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onPointerCaptureChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onPointerCaptureChanged
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15988: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onPointerCaptureChanged (Z)V
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15990: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15992: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15996: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 704: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.122 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 726: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
    12-11 13:46:44.152 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 485: Landroid/content/Context;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getCodeCacheDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 491: Landroid/content/Context;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColor, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 492: Landroid/content/Context;.getColor (I)I
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColorStateList
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDataDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDataDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 495: Landroid/content/Context;.getDataDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 496: Landroid/content/Context;.getDrawable (I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalCacheDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalCacheDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalCacheDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalFilesDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 500: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalFilesDirs (Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getNoBackupFilesDir, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 503: Landroid/content/Context;.getNoBackupFilesDir ()Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getObbDirs, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getObbDirs
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 505: Landroid/content/Context;.getObbDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
    12-11 13:46:44.192 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.isDeviceProtectedStorage
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 516: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.startForegroundService, referenced from method android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 531: Landroid/content/Context;.startForegroundService (Landroid/content/Intent;)Landroid/content/ComponentName;
    12-11 13:46:44.202 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.FrameLayout.startActionModeForChild, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.startActionModeForChild
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16457: Landroid/widget/FrameLayout;.startActionModeForChild (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
    12-11 13:46:44.442 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 493: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
    12-11 13:46:44.462 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.ImageButton.setImageIcon, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.setImageIcon
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16480: Landroid/widget/ImageButton;.setImageIcon (Landroid/graphics/drawable/Icon;)V
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 667: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 669: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
    12-11 13:46:44.492 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 193 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
    12-11 13:46:44.532 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16776: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMaxTextSize ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeMinTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16777: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeMinTextSize ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16779: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextAvailableSizes ()[I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeTextType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.getAutoSizeTextType
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16780: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeTextType ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16823: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration (IIII)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16824: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithPresetSizes ([II)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16825: Landroid/widget/TextView;.setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults (I)V
    12-11 13:46:44.632 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0006
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.getAutoSizeStepGranularity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextHelper.loadFromAttributes
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16778: Landroid/widget/TextView;.getAutoSizeStepGranularity ()I
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0197
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.obtain, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.createStaticLayoutForMeasuring
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 15266: Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;.obtain (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;IILandroid/text/TextPaint;I)Landroid/text/StaticLayout$Builder;
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0014
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.TextView.isInLayout, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextViewAutoSizeHelper.setRawTextSize
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16815: Landroid/widget/TextView;.isInLayout ()Z
    12-11 13:46:44.742 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
    12-11 13:46:45.053 12483-12483/com.example.teerna.testapp D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_java.so
```

Comment: what is the log you are getting with resonse tag?

Comment: I would guess that you are not getting a 200 response code back....

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I guess none, because I have already posted everything that's in the logcat

Comment: did youj try to filter with resonse tag

Comment: @TomMac Apparently. I am getting nothing in response to the JSON

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Nope. I am new to Android Studio and JSON as well. Can you please tell me what I can add in the filter?

Comment: https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/357670/feeds/last returns an HTTP Response Code = 400 for me. From what I can see your request to Thingspeak is returning nothing. Which might explain why nothing is showing.

Comment: there is a problem with your webservice. Your webservice is returning code 400.Contact with your backend developer

Comment: @TomMac my channel was actually 'private', I just made the channel 'public'.

Comment: @TomMac I have now set my channel to 'public' and initially it was 'private' which is why I was not getting a JSON response. I have got the following JSON response from my channel `12-11 18:55:44.720 6309-6356/com.example.teerna.testapp V/CatalogClient: {"created_at":"2017-12-02T09:37:26Z","entry_id":39,"field1":"6519"}` But still, nothing appears on my `TextView`

Comment: @AbdulWaheed  I have now set my channel to 'public' and initially it was 'private' which is why I was not getting a JSON response. I have got the following JSON response from my channel `12-11 18:55:44.720 6309-6356/com.example.teerna.testapp V/CatalogClient: {"created_at":"2017-12-02T09:37:26Z","entry_id":39,"field1":"6519"}` But still, nothing appears on my `TextView`